# child fork process return values

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, fork

In using Parallel::ForkManager, i have few doubts. As if i am calling child process in for loop, then who will execute the next statement , parent or child. Code:

```
   my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($forks);  foreach my $q (@numbers) {
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    my $res = calc($q); 
    if($res == error )
    {return};  
    if (#res == some_no)
    {do something and next;
    }
    $pm->finish(0, { result => $res, input => $q });
```

}....i want to know about fork return outputs and want parent process to execute 1st next and 2nd next. 
Also want to know if child process end in middle, will parent be able to know it and how?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager if you are interested in forking. I generally use 
https://metacpan.org/module/MCE which is also a good choice.

In case you don't want any external module use https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html. But you have to take care of everything here

Comment: 1) Mixing multithreading and multiprocessing is a bad idea in any case. I agree Parallel::ForkManager is great for this kind of thing. Also, the "forks" module provides an almost-identical interface to threads, except with processes.  However, it may not result in speed improvements, if they are all copying to/from the same disk. You don't magically double your drive's IO speeds.

Comment: Copy process speed improvement can be achieved only if you will copy from a number of sources to other number of destination. In case of mechanical disks positioning of read/write head takes most of time -- and parallel copy will cause read/write head to move more often, which results in drop of speed. In case of SSD drives speed improvement also should not be expected as controller has to switch more often to 'position' new block for each file handle. Speed improvement can be achieved only if copying taking place from disks As,Bs,Cs,Ds,... to Ad,Bd,Cd,Dd disks in parallel.

Comment: OS optimizes copy process (at development stage), special methods as RAID and RAM disks allows achieve better access/create/copy speeds, RAID by distributing IO and RAM disk by utilizing memory access which is much faster than access to physical disk.

Answer (score 2):

The two major sources of parallelism in perl are threading - `use threads;` and forking. For the latter, [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) is probably the best bet out there.

However, for copying? This may not help nearly as much as you think. Your limiting factor isn't going to be CPU, it'll be IO to disk.

Parallelising IO doesn't help nearly as much as you think, and in many cases can be counter-productive - by making the disk thrash, having to write to two locations, you lower overall throughput.

Comment: In using Parallel::ForkManager, i have few doubts. As if i am calling child process in for loop, then who will execute the next statement , parent or child. Code:                                         
   my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($forks);  foreach my $q (@numbers) {
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    my $res = calc($q); if($res == error ){return};  if (#res == some_no){do something and next;}
    $pm->finish(0, { result => $res, input => $q });
}....i want to know about this and want parent process to execute 1st next and 2nd next.